# Collapsing toolbar not scrolling smoothly as i expand it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Please first watch the video down the link below:
As you see there is no problem as i scroll up (makes the toolbar collapse) But as i try to expand the toolbar it is not coming down smoothly but in parts ! this thing is not happening if i use `layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways` also i do want the toolbar to collapse and pin to its original position.
i want this to scroll smoothly.
As i scroll to expand i want it to continuous and not to stop at collapse mode i dont want it to expand manually It should expand will just one scroll and smoothly.

Another question Is it necessary to use recycler view in `NestedScrollBar`  tag because i have seen lots of example doing this thing But it is working right even without `NestedScrollBar`.

please do give all the tags suggestions which i should use.Also Is there any way to increase scroll speed of toolbar?

here is what i am trying to say https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7ua27EMIDVfb3VMS1IxNU9XUGM

This is my `activity_main.xml` containing the collapsing toolbar layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="apackage.akash.newapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            >
            <include layout="@layout/app_bar"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this is my `app_bar.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: So, what is the problem? On video is standard CollapsingToolbar behavior

Comment: And no, you don't need to use NestedScrollView above RecyclerView to make it work. `RecyclerView`, `GridView`(support one) and `NestedScrollView` are already can work with `CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: Didn't you notice it scrolled so lazy as i expand it in the end for example just watch In  whatsapp if you go in view contact you will see the difference in scroll speed

Comment: I added some lines in my question just read those.

Comment: Hm, really no. It's pretty ok. Also, don't set android:fitsSystemWindows="true" everywhere, set it only for top parent

Comment: Toolbar collapsing speed depends on your scroll speed. This comes with material design guidelines.

Comment: `app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed"`remove this from toolbar

Comment: This is a known, and common issue (that apparently Google knows about for several years) with the default implementation of the Collapsing Toolbar. You'll find there are apps on the store that implement the default collapsing toolbar with non smooth transitions. There are some libraries that help address this issue ([example](https://github.com/henrytao-me/smooth-app-bar-layout), or [example2](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView))

Comment: what fitsSystemWindows ="true" actually do

Comment: @AkashKabir fitsSystemWindows allows or dissalows view to display behind status bar (thing in the top of screen). Useful only when it's transparent.

Comment: @akitsme have you found any solution for this issue ? Cause I am also facing the same issue, and I cant go for any other 3rd party  collapsing toolbar implementation .